# Read response body from Request with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have seen various posts about this topic but a lot are old

I have an issue where I need to track the content of a request that is coming from a HttpContextAccessor

At present, I use the extension method below

```
    public static string GetBody(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            request.Body.Position = 0;
            var result = new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Body not available";
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to get the content?  This doesnt work

Please note that I cant use Async because I call this method in a constructor

```
        public TenantService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
            ILogger<TenantService> logger,
            IOptions<AppConfiguration> tenantConfig)  
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _tenantConfig = tenantConfig.Value.Tenant;
            
            Tenant = new TenantDto();

            if (_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request != null)
            {
                SetupTenant($"{this.GetType().Name} - Via HttpContextAccessor");
            }
        }


    public void SetupTenant(string typeName)
    {
            var requestFullInfo = "No Request Available";
            var contextHeaders = HeadersFromContext;
            if (contextHeaders != null && contextHeaders.ContainsKey("TenantId"))
            {
                var tenant = TenantById(contextHeaders.GetGuidValue("TenantId"));
                ChangeViaTenant(tenant);
            }
            else
            {
                if (ContextRequest.LogNoTenantIdRequired())
                {
                    if (ContextRequest != null)
                    {
                        var requestBody = ContextRequest.GetBody();
                        var requestQueryString = ContextRequest.QueryString.ToString();
                        var requestPath = ContextRequest.Path.ToString();
                        var requestHost = ContextRequest.Host.ToString();

                        requestFullInfo = $"Host: {requestHost}. " +
                                          $"Body: {requestBody}. " +
                                          $"Query string: {requestQueryString}. " +
                                          $"Path: {requestPath}. ";
                    }

                    var message = $"No TenantId specified for {typeName} so using PVL.  Request Info: {requestFullInfo}";
                    _logger.LogWarning(message);
                }
                
                ChangeViaConfig(TenantCodes.Privalgo);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how we are getting requests coming in with no tenant id in the header hence the need for this logging

Cheers

Paul

Comment: "Please note that I cant use Async". Then you are doing something extremely bad. There is no good reason that you can't use async in a web api, and using sync method for this will have serious consequences over your api.

Comment: The method that calls this is a constructor which to my knowledge cannot be async

Comment: @Paul and why are you calling this in constructor?

Comment: Either you didn't use IServiceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor, or the request body has been already read in the controller method so that's why you are not reading anything.

Comment: Or it could be that you are in a non-http context thread, something like background job or something, we don't have that info, where this is called from.